# dotnet tool - authenticate using token non-interactively

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli, dotnet-tool

I'm setting up a system that is installing a tool via:

```
dotnet tool install MyTool --tool-path . --add-source <my-source-url>
```

The source I'm trying to get from is an [Azure artifacts feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops), and so will need authentication to access. Reading the `dotnet` tool's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-install), I can't seem to find a way to authenticate to a source e.g. via a personal access token.

Since this will be an automated system, I cannot use the `--interactive` flag. Are there workarounds for this or is there no way to authenticate for the `dotnet tool install` command?